# m-functions in Turing's paper "On Computable Numbers and applications..."

Tags: computability, turing-machines, logic, decision-problem

I was reading Alan Turing's paper "[On Computable Numbers with an Application to the Entscheidungsproblem](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf)".

I was reading well until I encountered "4. Abbreviated Tables", page 235-236, where Turing uses a new way of writing a computation table for a machine. I am totally lost here. I don not understand the examples he gives (starting from page 236) to explain the idea of *skeleton tables*.

I need help with understanding how skeleton tables are to be read, and what they mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

m-functions are quite similar to what we call today "macros". $f(\dots)$ is just the name of a supplementary m-configuration, that can be parameterized (like a macro). The trick is to not overthink it.

Comment: Where can I read about macros?

Comment: Well, if you don't know what a macro is, then my answer was not of great help. Check this out: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_(computer_science).

Comment: I understand macros, but still having trouble with m-functions. Does the parametrization mean that the m-function $f(...)$ is a m-configuration, which depends on the arguments on the function? If so, what is the format of the arguments? Does the m-function take in an m-configuration as argument and return another m-configuration?

Comment: The answers are: 1) yes, 2) the arguments are m-configurations or other m-functions (capital fraktur letters), or symbols (lowercase letters), 3) it takes what it takes [see 2)] and yes, returns itself, rewritten.

Comment: Suggestion: work out a complete example, a simple one, and edit your question adding it. I'll edit my answer accordingly, if necessary.